# Fastest way to get 10 random numbers from range

Tags: php

I want to get  10 random numbers from given range.

I use below code , But for larger range it is slow.Any alternative way to make it  as quick as possible.

```
$rangearr = array_rand(range(1,11892032), 5);
$rangearr  = implode(",",$rangearr);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

```
$randomnr = array();
$min = 1;
$max = 11892032;
for($i = 0; $i < 10;$i++) {
    $randomnr[] = mt_rand($min, $max);
}
echo implode(', ', $randomnr);
```

For unique numbers use this:

```
$randomnr = array();
$min = 1;
$max = 11892032;
$i = 1;
while($i <= 10) {
    $rand = mt_rand($min, $max);
    if(!in_array($rand,$randomnr)) {
        $randomnr[] = $rand
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Loading 11892032 values in an array, take its time, so you just generate 10 numbers.

Comment: @Vishnu nope, you must check it.

Comment: If you get the same number in a set of 10 numbers from 1 to more than 1 million, I'd eat my imaginary hat.

Comment: @Amarnasan Still it is possible (:

Comment: @Vishnu when my answer was helping you, mark it as correct.

Comment: @JannisM: you forgot a bracket here: `if(!in_array($rand,$randomnr)--->) <---{`

Answer (score 1):

So I threw this together

```
<?php

// range
$timer = microtime(true);

$rangearr = array_rand(range(1,11892032), 5);
$rangearr  = implode(",",$rangearr);

echo number_format(microtime(true) - $timer, 5) . '<br>';

// fixed range
$timer = microtime(true);

$range = range(1, 11892032);
$rangearr = array_rand($range, 5);
$rangearr  = implode(",",$rangearr);

echo number_format(microtime(true) - $timer, 5) . '<br>';

// for loop
$timer = microtime(true);

$rangearr = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    $rangarr[] = rand(1, 11892032);
}

echo number_format(microtime(true) - $timer, 5) . '<br>';
```

I get these results

```
1.93242
1.18987
0.00002
```

I'd go with the for loop approach!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-liner:

```
$min = 1;
$max=11892032;
echo implode(',', array_map(function()use($min,$max){return mt_rand($min, $max);},range(0,9)));
```

Comment: If everybody understood one-liner as you do, everything in PHP could be made with one line

Comment: and I see three lines, I like it though

Comment: @Dale: But look what are the first two lines! If you really-really want a one-liner, you can replace the $min,$max values in the array_map closure, but I wanted to show that you don't need to hard-code the closure to make it work

Comment: I don't like it anymore

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
$arr = array();
$min = 1;
$max = 11892032 + 1; // important +1
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr[] = (mt_rand() + $min) % $max;
}
```

To read before sleep: http://pageconfig.com/post/faster-random-numbers-with-php

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this snippet below, it's way faster than `range()` and will you provide an almost secure integer or in this case a float without decimal places, you can also cast it to int before returning.

I also checked for doublettes in the loop, so if you want five unique numbers (`$randomNumberCount = 5;`) you'll get it.

**BEWARE:** if an error occurs, read the comments in my code.

**Working example:**

```
function secure_rand( $min, $max ) {
    $diff = $max - $min;
    if ($diff < 0 || $diff > 0x7FFFFFFF) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bad range");
    }

    // if mcrypt is enabled try this
    //$bytes = mcrypt_create_iv( 4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM );

    // if mcrypt is not enabled on your server, you can use this
    $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( 4 );

    // if mbstring is not enabled, you can also use iconv_strlen
    if ($bytes === false || mb_strlen($bytes, '8bit') != 4) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get 4 bytes");
    }

    $ary = unpack("Nint", $bytes);
    $val = $ary['int'] & 0x7FFFFFFF;   // 32-bit safe
    $fp = $val / 2147483647.0; // convert to [0,1]
    // if you really need a type of int take this
    // return (int) round($fp * $diff) + $min;
    // otherwise it will return a float without decimal numbers
    return round($fp * $diff) + $min;
}


$randomNumbers = array();
$randomNumberCount = 5;
$min = 1;
$max = 11892032;

while( count( $randomNumbers ) < $randomNumberCount ) {
    $rand = secure_rand( $min, $max );
    // check for doublettes
    if( in_array( $rand, $randomNumbers ) ) continue;

    $randomNumbers[] = $rand;
}

$randomNumbers = implode( ",", $randomNumbers );

echo $randomNumbers;
```